# How to make button Blink in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I'm working on UWP quizz app and I want to let user know that he selected right or wrong answer by making selected button blink. I tried some code used in WPF but it isn't working. Is it possible in UWP?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what code isn't working

Comment: Give us the code you tried.  Does it error in UWP or does it just do nothing?  Are there any messages in the error log? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's absolutely possible. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451495/blink-image-3-times-and-stop/39453076#39453076) I did recently you can check for reference, I think the only thing necessary to port it from WPF to UWP in that example would be just changing "FrameworkElement.Loaded" to just "Loaded" but the storyboard I think would port over without issue.

Comment: Sorry for asking, already found solution

Answer (score 1):

`<Storyboard 
                                    x:Name="ButtonBlink"
                                    BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="00:00:05"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="PrvniOdpovedButton" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
            <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1"/>`

Already found solution. Thanks